# Looking to store YouTube video data into my Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to build a Rails app that uses the YouTube data API provided through the YouTube_it gem.  So far I have been successful in being able to pull the data from YouTube and list it on a webpage but its pretty slow.  I would like to just make a request maybe once a day to the YouTube data and store it in my database so that my app would just use my database.  Is this a good idea? Are there better ways to do this?  And how do I do this?  I know I need to build a model but without a form, how do I update the database, say once a day/once a week?

I know these are a lot of questions but any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around enough I found the answer to my question.  Basically what I needed to do was use a rake task to connect to youtube_it and store the youtube data into my database and then use cron or the gem 'whenever' to run that task at certain time periods.

Answer (score 0):

For your background processing [Delayed Job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) works well and is easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't quite what I was looking for but it is a good source.